# PowerShell - Can't Pipe Loop Output

Tags: powershell

I need to pipe output from group of **Write-Host** calls to **Out-Host** with paging, since the output is often voluminous.

The following code seems to do the piping OK, but it ignores the “-paging” argument. That, I get the expected output lines, but they scroll off the screen instead of showing one screen’s worth at a time.

```
$queue = Find-FilesToUpload -server $server | Sort-Object -property lastWriteTime
$(
   Write-Host("`n{0,-38} {1,-25} {2,7}" -f "Name", "Last Written", "Size")
   Write-Host "------------------------------------------------------------------------"
   foreach  ($file in $queue) {
      Write-Host("{0,-38} {1,-23} {2,9:n0}" -f $file.name, $file.lastWriteTime, $file.length)
   }
) | Out-Host -Paging
```

How do I enable paging?

Comment: `Write-Host` already writes _directly to the host_, so there's no stream output for `Out-Host` to handle. Change `Write-Host` to `Write-Output`, or simply remove it

Comment: Wow. It works. I would never have guessed that was the issue. Guess I still have a lot of learning ahead (I'm new to PS). Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kudos to Mathias R. Jessen, who pointed out that **Write-Host** doesn't produce pipe-able output. After removing those calls, the code works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Pipe to more and write-output seem to give better results for me.  Out-host -paging stopped at every line.  Enclosing in & { } is another option, but didn't make a difference in this case.

```
$( foreach ($i in 1..100) { write-output hi } ) | more
```